# Check is netmask correct

Tags: c, network-programming, netmask

Hello i have such netmask, f.e. 255.128.0.0, it is correct netmask, i need to check it.

```
int s; 
struct in_addr ipvalue;
s = inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &ipvalue);
```

and if i print `s` i see `33023` witch in binary form is `00000000.00000000.10000000.11111111`, but this is not equals to my input netmask, so how i can check is my netmask is correct or not? Now i am cheking it by comparing netmask in decimal form and `for (int i = 31; i >=0; i--) sm |= (1 << i);`
Thank you.

Comment: Define "correct" in this context. And what do you mean "not equals my input ip"? A netmask should not *equal* any ip.

Comment: i mean netmask, correct is that all `1` bits follow each other, i mean , netmask can't be `10.0.0.1`

Comment: But netmask can be 255.128.0.0. As such it is likely that you outputting the netmask as though it was just a normal number is likely the problem here. That netmask is better represented as 11111111.10000000.00000000.00000000

Comment: yes, but inet_pton returns me wildcard notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i print s i see 33023 witch in binary form is 00000000.00000000.10000000.11111111

Your problem looks like an endianness issue.

Try the following:

```
int s; 
struct in_addr ipvalue;
s = inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &ipvalue);
s = ntohl(s);
```

That should fix the byte order issue.

Answer (score 0):

whatever you have done, it is correct! But `inet_pton` returns the converted subnetmask in Big   endianness form. so you need to convert it to Little endianness. Then you will get your actual subnetmask.

And you should not print `s`, because the return value of conversion is stored in `s`. Try to print structure member of `ipvalue`. `struct in_addr` contains-

```
struct in_addr {
unsigned long s_addr;  
};
```

so while converting from network byte order to host byte order use `ipvalue.s_addr`!

Try the following code-

```
    int s,i;
    struct in_addr ipvalue;
    unsigned long num;

    s = inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &ipvalue);

    num=ntohl(ipvalue.s_addr); // converts network to host byte order!

    for(i=31;i>=0;i--){
            if(num&1<<i)
                    printf("1");
            else
                    printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
```